# Laravel echo server won't start

Tags: laravel, socket.io, echo, centos7

Laravel echo server keeps returning `failed` status on my server

## Code

`laravel-echo-server.json`

```
{
    "authHost": "http://example.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "311dr094tf98745ce",
            "key": "fa43bffb3rth63f5ac9c386916ae28e6"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": false,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:80",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

`echo-pm2.json`

```
{
  "name": "echo",
  "script": "laravel-echo-server.json",
  "args": "start"
}
```

then i run `pm2 start echo-pm2.json` and status is `online` but when i visit my web page i keep getting

```
GET https://www.example.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NA2SNHk net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

The problem was my url was set to `https` *(GET https://www.example.com)* while my actual address is running on `http` *(GET http://www.example.com)*

so that extra `S`... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"authHost": "http://example.com"
```

I have this set to the url of my localhost, not sure if it helps you